# What's wrong with my ponytail palm?

Tags: houseplants, leaves

[image]The white spots are also on new leaves and cannot be removed by a cloth. I haven't been able to detect any bugs on the plant, except some tiny black dots on the leaves close to the stem.

Answer (score 1):

The brown tips of the leaves and the gray areas look likes damages from drought in combination with too much **direct** sunlight.

Even [Beaucarnea recurvata](https://www.rhsplants.co.uk/plants/_/beaucarnea-recurvata/classid.2000032096/) is a succulent and loves bright light and dislikes overwatering, it needs some water under hot and sunny conditions. During the winter it needs only small amounts of water, but in the summertime you should supply more water or place it in indirect sunlight.

It can be hard to estimate its needs, so let it soak for about 20 minutes and then remove the water it did not absorb. It is fine to let the soil become dry before you water. The big trunk is a kind of water reservoir.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. For now the plan is sitting on a south west window. I am gonna move it away from window. The leaves are starting to get sticky and the tiny black bugs are also increasing in number. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Tiny black bugs causing sticky leaves are most likely aphids. And yes, you should be concerned because aphids have no natural enemies indoor. Try an insect soap or liquid castile soap. https://thebugagenda.com/killing-aphids-with-soapy-water/#:~:text=Soaps%20work%20by%20interrupting%20the%20cell%20membranes%20of,covered%20in%20soap%20that%20it%E2%80%99s%20smothered%20to%20death.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. Thank you for your help <3